# Azure after shrinking disk - Not able to mount

Tags: linux, azure

I am trying to shrink a data disk (512 -> 256 GB) attached to same Linux VM (Centos) in Azure . I followed the link https://github.com/jrudlin/Azure/blob/master/General/Shrink-AzDisk.ps1 to do shrinking. I am able to create new shrunk disk (sde) and attach it to the same VM.
[image: lsblk output]

I tried to mount in a different path and i get the below error
[image: mount error]

When i run pvs command, i get the below output.
[image: pvs output]

I ran lvmdiskscan and got the below output
[image: lvmdisckscan]

I tried to run pvcreate and got the below error.
[image: error]

I want to understand is it possible to mount new disk.

Comment: Are you trying to mount the same disk after shrunk to different location is it?

Comment: I am want to mount it to a different mount point on the same vm. Eventually want to remove the original disk and retain the shrunk disk only. I tried detaching the original disk , removing the current pv, vg and lv. Tried to create to a new pv,vg and lv in the same name and mount it, but get below error - mount: /srv: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/test, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.